# Can't run after adding location package

Tags: flutter, geolocation, flutter-dependencies

I can't run after adding location package i guess the problem in kotlin gradle
[this is the error as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2FJq.png)

i tried to change kotlin version but nothing done.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator Try this package. it's an alternative to the location package. and it should work well with new kotlin verison.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)